# Shopware 6 OneToMany relation

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am going to define a OneToMany relation in the Shopware 6 .in my case  i am going  to have an article linked with many tags.
I understand that those situations can be too complex in the Shopware and depends on many things. and it is hard to help.
But if  introduce to me a tutorial or code example, it will help me

```php
use AkArticle\Core\Content\Tag\tagCollection;

//My ArticleEntity

class ArticleEntity extends Entity
{
    
        /**
         * @var TagCollection|null
         */
        protected $tag;
        protected $tagId;
    
    public function getTagId(){ return $this->tagId; }
    public function setTagId($value): void { $this->tagId = $value; }

    public function getTag(): ?TagCollection
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function setTag(TagCollection $tag): void
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }
    
    // rest of the code
    
}
```

```php
// ArticleDefinition

    
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace AkArticle\Core\Content\Article;
    
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityDefinition;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\PrimaryKey;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\IdField;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\StringField;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\BoolField;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\TranslatedField;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\TranslationsAssociationField;
    use AkArticle\Core\Content\Aggregate\ArticleTranslation\ArticleTranslationDefinition;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToManyAssociationField;
    use AkTag\Core\Content\Tag\TagDefinition;
    
    class ArticleDefinition extends EntityDefinition
    {
        public const ENTITY_NAME = 'ak_artcle_plugin';
        public function getEntityName(): string
        {
            return self::ENTITY_NAME;
        }
    
        public function getEntityClass(): string
        {
            return ArticleEntity::class;
        }
        public function getCollectionClass(): string
        {
            return ArticleCollection::class;
        }
    
        protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
        {
            return new FieldCollection([
                (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
                (new StringField('name', 'name'))->addFlags(new Required()),
                (new BoolField('active','active'))->addFlags(new Required()),
                (new TranslatedField('title')),
                new IdField('tagId', 'tagId'),
    
              new TranslationsAssociationField(ArticleTranslationDefinition::class, 'ak_article_plugin_id'),
                new OneToManyAssociationField('tag', TagDefinition::class, 'id'),
    
            ]);
        }
}
```

article-detals.html.twig

```html
    <sw-multi-select 
        :label="$t('ak-article.detail.label.name-tag')" 
        :options="tags"
        v-model="article.tagId"
    >
    </sw-multi-select>
```

[image]

after submit i get this error

```json
    {
    "0":
    {
        "code": "FRAMEWORK__WRITE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION",
        "status": "400",
        "detail": "This value should be of type string.",
        "template": "This value should be of type string.",
        "meta":
        {
            "parameters": []
        },
        "source":
        {
            "pointer": "/0/tagId"
        }
    }
}
```

What is my wrong .I tried to found  a solution but can't found anything .I tried to found to some codes example close to my situation but i don't succeed.

Comment: Please show the whole code of your EntityDefinition otherwise i am unable to help.

Comment: Hi Sebastian.i have updated the question .thake you

Comment: Do you really want a oneToMany relation between tags and Articles? Meaning an article can have only one tag or do you need a ManyToMany rmeaning articles can have multiple tags, and tags can be assigned to multiple articles.

With the oneToMany you will need a `sw-single-select` in the administration instead of a multi select.

Comment: Hi.I want  to have an article which related to tags .(an article can have multiple tags). So i supposed to use ManytoMany relationship .thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a many to many association between the article and tag entity.
Therefore you need to create a MappingDefinition, this is explained in detail in the [docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle/entity-association).

To display that association in the administration you can use the [`sw-entity-many-to-many-select`](https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-entity-many-to-many-select).